# Does this product converges in $L^1$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, convergence-divergence, random-variables

Suppose $(X_n)$ is a discrete sequence of independent and equally distributed random variables such that : $E[X_3]=1$ and $P(X_3=\alpha)$ +$P(X_3=\beta)=1$.

Does the product $P_n=\Pi_{k=1}^n X_n$ converges in $L^1$?

my attempt is that : $E[P_n]=(E[X]^n)=1$ so it doesn't converge but I'm not sure

Edit: I forgot to add that $\alpha$ is in $]0,1[$ and $\beta \gt \alpha$

Comment: Well, the first way that it would spectacularly fail to do that is if either $\alpha$ or $\beta$ is negative.

Comment: @ian1 I edited the question, forgot to add the information about $\alpha$ and $\beta$ sorry

Comment: Besides that, consider the simple calculation $E[P_{n+1} \mid P_n]=E[X_{n+1}] P_n=P_n$. Thus you have a martingale. There is some general theory for convergence of martingales.

Comment: In general the requirement for convergence in $L^1$ here is uniform integrability, which I *think* you can show actually does not hold, and thus prove $P_n$ does not converge in $L^1$. Doing this by hand needs some estimation work with the binomial distribution, since the situation basically comes down to controlling the number of times that $X_n=\beta$.

Comment: Yeah, the key computation comes down to finding $\sum_{k=K}^n P(Z=k) \beta^k \alpha^{n-k}$ where $Z$ is binomial($n,P(X=\beta)$) distributed. So given $\epsilon>0$, can you find $K_\epsilon$ such that this is less than $\epsilon$ whenever $K>K_\epsilon$ (independent of $n$) or not? If you can't then you're just done, no martingale theory required. If you can then the desired result follows by Doob's second martingale convergence theorem.

Comment: @Ian I'm not familar with stochastic processes yet so I have little to no idea what martingale theory is. I'll google it and try to understand what you said. Thank you for taking your time to comment :).

Comment: If you can answer that last question then I can just write an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A necessary condition for convergence in $L^1(dP)$ is uniform integrability, i.e. that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $K_\epsilon>0$ such that for all $n$, $\int_{|X_n| \geq K_\epsilon} |X_n| dP<\epsilon$.

So now here, what is that integral? It is $\sum_{k : \beta^k \alpha^{n-k} \geq K_\epsilon} {n \choose k} (\beta p_2)^k (\alpha p_1)^{n-k}$. So the sum starts at $k^*+1:=\left \lceil \frac{\log(K_\epsilon)}{\log(\beta)-\log(\alpha)} \right \rceil$ assuming $n \geq k^*+1$.

From the binomial theorem, if it started at $0$ it would be $(\alpha p_1+\beta p_2)^n=1$ so if $n \geq k^*$ then you have $1-\sum_{k=0}^{k^*} {n \choose k} (\beta p_2)^k (\alpha p_1)^{n-k}$. So the question is, what happens when you send $n \to \infty$ in this sum for fixed $k^*$? In this case eventually the last term dominates and so you are essentially looking at $1-{n \choose k^*} (\alpha p_1)^n \left ( \frac{\beta p_2}{\alpha p_1} \right )^{k^*}$ which goes to $1$ (${n \choose k^*}$ has only polynomial growth which loses to the exponential decay of the other term).

Thus $X_n$ is not uniformly integrable and thus it does not converge in $L^1$.

What is interesting about this result is that the process converges in probability to zero (and from numerical simulations seems to converge a.s. also, but I didn't check this). But the large deviations in the binomial are likely enough to spoil the $L^1$ convergence nonetheless, because you have "just the right amount" of "exponential tilting" through the function $x \mapsto \beta^x \alpha^{n-x}$, a classic situation in large deviation theory.

Actually, in view of that observation, you get an alternate, more abstract, less technical proof: $X_n$ converges in probability to $0$, so if it converges in $L^1$ to something then that something must be $0$, but $\| X_n-0 \|_{L^1}=1$ by the binomial theorem.

Side remark: this process is a martingale, since $E[X_{n+1} \mid X_n]=p_2 \beta X_n + p_1 \alpha X_n=X_n$. Doob's second martingale convergence theorem says that uniform integrability is *sufficient* for convergence in $L^1$ for martingales. So this check of uniform integrability was especially reasonable in this problem, because if we had gotten the other outcome then we would still know what was happening.